# visual basic 2010 copy paste subroutine

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to write 2 simple subroutines in VB 2010 that could be used with toolstripbutton contorls for multiple textboxes in a form. I know simple copy paste could be done using the textbox1.Copy() and TextBox1.Paste() methodes. What i am trying to do is write a common subroutine which could be used on any textboxes in the form not just one particular textbox.
My codes are below, I know there are errors in it, just wondering how it could be achieved. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
Public Class Form1
 Private Sub copytext()
    Dim txt As Control
    If TypeOf txt Is TextBox Then
        Clipboard.Clear()
        Clipboard.SetText(txt.SelectedText)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub pastetext()
    Dim txt As Control
    If TypeOf txt Is TextBox Then
        txt.Text = Clipboard.GetText
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub mnuCopy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuCopy.Click
    Call copytext()
End Sub

Private Sub mnuPaste_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuPaste.Click
    Call pastetext()
End Sub
End Class
```